# Update Value in Text File based on Value from another Dictionary in Loop

Tags: c#, algorithm

Let say I have text file that store log data

```
2019-03-01 20:00:18; Value1; Value2
2019-03-01 20:00:23; Value1; Value2
2019-03-01 20:00:28; Value1; Value2
```

and I have Value in Dictionary

```
ID = Value1
StartDateTime = 2019-03-01 20:00:18
OffDateTime = 2019-03-01 20:00:27
Value = 9
```

I want to update Value1 in all record in text file which the duration is between StartDateTime and OffDateTime.

In this case, it will update the 1st and 2nd rows.

Right now I'm using this

```
if (textFileCurrentLineDateTime >= StartDateTime && textFileNextLineDateTime < OffDateTime)
{
   //this line need to update value
}
```

which is working fine if the duration of StartDateTime and OffDateTime is not more than 1 record.

Comment: Do you mean you want to update data in text file?

Comment: Yes, I already have code to handle the update process but the problem now is mainly on my condition to write the update.

Comment: I don't understand what *working fine if the duration of StartDateTime and OffDateTime is not more than 1 record* means. Can you please explain?

Comment: OK, if we change the OffDateTime to 20:00:23, it'll update only the the first record which is work as intended. But in the above example I have OffDateTime that cover the 2nd record as well. So I expect it to update the 2nd record but it's not.

Comment: I think you will have to show some of your code if you want any one to provide some help.

Answer (score 0):

```
   internal class Program
{
    private static Line CreateLineFromString(string line)
    {
        string[] array = line.Split(';');

        return new Line
        {
            DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(array[0],CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            Value1 = array[1],
            Value2 = array[2]
        };
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        IEnumerable<Line> lines = ReadLines().ToList();

        var startDate = new DateTime(2019, 1, 1);
        var endDate = new DateTime(2019, 6, 30);

        foreach (Line line in lines.Where(line => line.DateTime >= startDate && line.DateTime <= endDate)) line.Value1 = "New Value";

        SaveLines(lines);
    }


    private static IEnumerable<Line> ReadLines()
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader("d:\\TextFile1.txt"))
        {
            string stringLine;
            while ((stringLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                if (stringLine != string.Empty)
                    yield return CreateLineFromString(stringLine);

        }
    }

    private static void SaveLines(IEnumerable<Line> lines)
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter("d:\\TextFile1.txt",false))
        {
            foreach (Line line in lines) writer.WriteLine(line.ToString());
        }
    }
}


public class Line
{
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public string Value1 { get; set; }

    public string Value2 { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{DateTime.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)};{Value1};{Value2}";
    }
}
```